# Is a 2014 Mac mini fully compatible with Sierra?

Tags: mac-mini

I bought a 2014 late Mac mini today from a shop where it was a test device. It has been registered but I got it cheaper. My problem is: it has macOS Sierra installed on it, which runs very slow, and the finder seems to be messed up. It does not show any file content.

Mac mini specifications:

- CPU: Dual-core i5 1.4 GHz
- RAM: 4 GB
- HDD: 500 GB

Are current Mac mini devices shipped with Sierra, or it has been upgraded from El Capitan? It has been registered in 15 May 2017. Is this model fully and sufficiently compatible with macOS Sierra?

Comment: What exactly is your question here?

Comment: I'm running Sierra on a 2011 Mini without problems or signs of it being overloaded.  Any used computer I bought would get an *immediate* OS reinstall because there's no way to know what's installed on it, including malware.  The thing could be mining bitcoin for all you know.

Comment: I've expanded the title to be more specific about the problem you are having as just saying ‘problems’ doesn't help anyone else looking for this question. Feel free to [edit] to better summarise the question you are asking

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest re-installing the latest macOS that was installed on your Mac, without upgrading to a later version. This can be accomplished by pressing and holding `Command-R` immediately after pressing the power button to turn on your Mac mini.

Source: https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204904

Comment: A 2014 Mac Mini is perfectly capable of running Sierra with reasonable performance. Reinstalling the OS is a good starting point, but I would upgrade to Sierra nevertheless from there.